# Does Craft Commerce support multi-channel fulfillment and inventory?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, localization

I have a client with several retail locations. They would like a single unified website for the chain, and many of the products will be the same at each location, but each location will need to handle its own orders, including fulfillment and inventory. Users should only have access to orders that pertain to their location (similar to how sections can be limited to certain users). Is there a native way to do this with Craft Commerce, or a plugin that would achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, out of the box, no it does not, currently.  Inventory handling is quite basic at the moment, for example.

You could probably deal with a lot of the access stuff via Craft users & permissions, but there's no doubt in my mind this would involve a very substantial amount of custom plugin development work, and I'm reasonable sure no such plugin currently exists.

Commerce is still a relatively young product, so who knows about the future, but right now it would not personally be my first choice for this sort of project.

(You could perhaps tackle them as separate installations and use things like the ElementAPI to push product content between the systems, though, if the key issue is content sharing as opposed to one unified back end).